# Can aqua regia/royal water dissolve lead?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, halides, pnictogen

As known aqua regia can't dissolve $\ce{Ag}$ because formation of $\ce{AgCl}$ precipitate. Similarly will aqua regia precipitate $\ce{Pb}$ as $\ce{PbCl2}$? **OR** It is not possible to observe this because aqua regia produce heat keeping solution warm ($\ce{PbCl2}$ is soluble in hot water).

Comment: The one who wants to reopen the question please tell the reason. If you want to answer the question you may answer linked question or edit Nilay's answer after asking him. I myself has accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqua regia doesn't actually dissolve lead metal. It converts to insoluble lead salt. From [here](https://goldrefiningforum.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=21212):

> When we are working with an acidic chloride solution, like HCl (with
> an oxidizer) or **aqua regia, most of the lead will become an insoluble
> lead chloride** which if it is left to settle can be removed by careful
> decanting of the solution and filtering, what lead does carry through
> the process with this solution can then be removed with a few drops of
> sulfuric acid, and precipitated out of solution as a lead sulfate.

Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4lIXX0vJ7U) for your reference.